# Permanent redirect from Github gh-pages

Tags: http, redirect, github, jekyll, github-pages

I want to create a homepage and, for now, I think Github's pages features will serve my needs. However, I might want to switch to a more full-blown CMS/blog engine later on.

Is it possible to serve a permanent redirect (HTTP 301) from Github pages in case I decide to move my homepage someplace else while preserving all the old URIs?

Comment: You may want to +1 this feature over at the Github support forum.

Comment: I can't find this feature request on github.

Comment: Do you want to mass redirect as `you.github.io/some/path` to `new_domain.com/some/path`? Or only individual redirects? I propose we keep this for mass redirect since individual redirects are covered at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178304/what-is-the-best-approach-for-redirection-of-old-pages-in-jekyll-and-github-page and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276817/301-redirect-for-site-hosted-at-github?lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best I can deduce is that Github has not yet added this. See [Tekkub response from April 2010](http://support.github.com/discussions/repos/2959-permanent-redirect-for-github-pages-project) re: adding it to the feature request list. Another message [from another user in January](http://support.github.com/discussions/site/2954-github-pages-http-redirect) suggests a META tag as a workaround (probably not a good solution).

Comment: Ah yes, closed because it's now "on The List" -- where have I seen that one before? The `meta` workaround is ugly, but if it's good enough to fool Google, I might give it a try.

Comment: both links are broken.. any chances of restoring those?

Answer (score 1):

**Mass redirect layout technique**

Individual page redirects are covered at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36846720/895245 Actual 301s seem impossible.

If you want to mass redirect:

```
http://you.github.io/some/path
```

to:

```
http://new_domain.com/some/path
```

do as follows.

**Before you move away**

- `_layouts/default.html`: the default layout
- `_config` uses the default layout:

  ```
  defaults:
    -
      scope:
        path: ''
      values:
        layout: 'default'
  ```

**After you move away**

- create `_layouts/redirect.html` with an HTML redirect derived from [Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page) along:

  ```
  {% assign redir_to = site.new_domain | append: page.url %}
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Redirecting...</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="{{ redir_to }}"/>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url={{ redir_to }}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Redirecting...</h1>
    <a href="{{ redir_to }}">Click here if you are not redirected.<a>
    <script>location='{{ redir_to }}'</script>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- `_config` contains:

  ```
  defaults:
    -
      scope:
        path: ''
      values:
        layout: 'redirect'
  new_domain: 'http://new-domain.com/some/path
  ```
- replace every non-default layout with a symlink to the `redirect` layout. This is the only ugly part of this technique. I don't see a beautiful non-plugin solution.

Answer (score 1):

For the security of their users, GitHub Pages does not support customer server configuration files such as .htaccess or .conf. However, using the Jekyll Redirect From plugin, you can automatically redirect visitors to the updated URL.

More info can be found here: https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Shortly, set up CNAME redirection by [setting a custom domain on your GitHub Pages settings](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site).

This is usually the case when you want your GitHub Pages to be served through a custom domain (let's say the user tries to access https://kamarada.github.io/, then the browser redirects to https://linuxkamarada.com/, but the pages are indeed on GitHub).

But it also works in the case when you previously had your website served by GitHub Pages and moved to another server, e.g. GitLab Pages (I imagine that could work for e.g. WordPress as well).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66601856/1657502): the user tries to access https://kamarada.github.io/, then the browser redirects to https://linuxkamarada.com/, but the pages are actually on GitLab.