# My Index Redirecting

Tags: indexing

my website index address is like this :

```
index.php?sid=8
```

we create new sid each week . for example next week is 9 , then 10 , then ... .
we wanna redirect all users to the last sid we created. how can I do this?
tnx

Comment: The usual behaviour I've seen is to have the main site (index.php or whatever) link to the current site. If you want specifics you'll have to more specific regarding the environment (e.g. languages) (and add appropriate tags for this).

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I said , however thank you

Comment: All users can go to say `redirect.php` by default. `redirect.php` can exist solely to redirect to `index.php?sid=X` (the latest). This can be done by having the value hard-coded into the script (and you change it when you add a new sid), having it stored in a separate file, or actually checking which sid's exist. I'm not really sure what sid's are, or where you want to put this redirection (there are a lot of options). If this is a simple redirect question, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-html-page).