# introduction for a website

Tags: web

I want to know how to make introduction page which lasts couple seconds and then takes you to the home page of website. That is, when someone types my domain name I need a page to introduce to subject of my website.

Answer (score 1):

This would be what you could use to redirect the site, change the content to the amount of seconds you want the viewer to stay on the page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://whatever.org/">
```

Referenced from **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-html-page)**

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in 2 ways,

1. create a pop up and use javascript setTimeOut() for delay
2. make index page as your subject of the website and use setTimeOut() for delay and then reidrect to your home page.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use javascript to redirect. This example redirects the page after 2 seconds:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function foo()
{
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
}
setTimeout(foo, 2000);
</script>
```