# How to modify array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I currently have an array of objects where each object has several properties.  Example:

```
[
   { text: 'test1',
     id: 1
   },
   { text: 'test2',
     id: 2
   }
]
```

What would be the best way to convert this to an array of strings that contains the value from `text`?  I had thought I might be able to do this using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#pick):

```
headerText = _.pick(headerRow, 'text');
```

But I think that since the objects are in an array this will not work.  My next idea is to just loop through each element in the array and push the `text` value to a new array, but i'm curious if anyone knows of a more elegant way to do this? Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`Array#map`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19):

```
var stringArray = headerRow.map(function(entry) {
    return entry.text;
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uvoroh/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/uvoroh/1/edit)

You don't even need Underscore, `Array#map` is part of ES5 and fully supported by V8, the JavaScript engine used by Node. `Array#map` calls the function you give it once for each entry in the array, and builds a new array from the return values of that function.

Or if you want to change the *existing* array, you can use [`Array#forEach`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18):

```
headerRow.forEach(function(entry, index) {
    headerRow[index] = entry.text;
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uvoroh/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/uvoroh/2/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Use `_.map(headerRow, function(row) { return row.text; })`. `Array.map` isn't available in IE < 9.

Comment: *"Array.map isn't available in IE < 9."* So? The OP says they're using Node. Node uses V8, which has `Array#map`.

Comment: This is node.js (server side javascript) so IE 9 won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

i'd use a foreach and just loop through it.

```
 var jamie = [
    { text: 'test1',
      id: 1
    },
    { text: 'test2',
      id: 2
    }
 ];

 var length = jamie.length,
     element = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   element[i] = jamie[i].id;
   // Do something with element i.
 }
   console.info(element);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a vanilla javascript version, which avoids using the not universally supported `Array.map` method.

```
// assign the array to a variable
var a = [
   { text: 'test1',
     id: 1
   },
   { text: 'test2',
     id: 2
   }
];

// loop through each item in the array, reassigning with it's text value
// not like this: for(i in a) a[i] = a[i].text
// but with a for loop based on the array length
var i;
for(i=a.length; i; i--){ a[i-1] = a[i-1].text; }

// check the results
console.log(a);
// ["test1", "test2"]
```

Comment: `for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){stringArray.push(row.text)}`

Comment: Note: comment seems to have gone linking to [why not to use `for...in` to enumerate arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)

Comment: `for i in a` could find undesired prototypical stuff

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the thoughtful insight. I am only coding like this for demonstration here, in my own code, I will add semicolons etc... but I feel that it is more useful to put as little in there that does not directly relate to the question (global declarations / semi-colons/etc..). There was recently an issue with someone copy/pasting my code from stack overflow, causing the stack overflow site to come second in google when searching for `stack overflow`, so maybe I should start writing more pristine code from now on.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder do you think that there is a problem with the `anti-pattern` way of using a for-loop? Is it for readability that it is not advised?

Comment: @BillyMoon: Maintainability, which encompasses readability, yes. I have a rule about `for` loops: If you're not using each of the three parts of it, and for its primary purpose, use a different kind of loop. In this case, for instance, if you wanted to use the decrement trick I'd've recommended `i = a.length; while (i--) { ... }`. (Personally, I just prefer the `for` starting with `- 1`.) As for the other stuff, people absolutely **will** use your code verbatim, so making it less than you believe to be the correct standard is probably not serving them very well.

Comment: @BillyMoon: ...and I'm pretty sure stackoverflow.com has been the first Google hit for `stack overflow` for a long time now. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169405/google-indexing-issue-for-keyword-stackoverflow) and [this](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5311151) and see the [troublesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-html-page/5411601#5411601) of mine causing the issue