# How can I redirect maintenance site in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ihttphandler

We have a ASP.NET website in .NET which is running successfully in production. we have frequently maintain our server on a particular downtime. Hence, We need a feature to redirect all request to Site Under maintenance web page at downtime. I've accomplished this task with Custom Handler but my customer isn't happy with that solution. Please suggest some alternate solution.

My Custom Handler code as follows

Added Under web.config

```
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
          <add name="CustomModule" type="CustomModule"/>
       </modules>
  </system.webserver>
```

Added Under Http Handler

```
public class CustomModule : IHttpModule
    {
        // In the Init function, register for HttpApplication 
        // events by adding your handlers.
        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {

            application.EndRequest +=
                (new EventHandler(this.Application_EndRequest));
        }
}
```

Redirect code goes here

```
private void Application_EndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (fileExtension.Equals(".aspx") == true && filePath.Contains("Contact.aspx") == false)
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("Contact.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why isn't the customer happy with this?

Comment: It's already in production. So they wouldn't like to implement custom handler.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2012/02/03/easiest-way-to-take-your-web-site-offline-iis-6-0-or-iis-7-5-with-net-4-0.aspx  assuming you are on  recent iis version

Comment: I'm in .NET 2.0 version

Comment: Somebody posted on the link from @rene it could work in 2.0

Comment: From your responses, it sounds like you paradoxically want to run custom code, but without deploying any code to the server.  You can't accomplish both goals.

Comment: How about adding a meta refresh tag to the app_offline.html like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-html-page) answer

Comment: @rene - I don't think he'd be able to redirect to the main site with an app_offline.  It would probably just redirect back to itself infinitely.

Comment: @Greg, hmmm, you are probably right...it seems to be a catch 22 in that case...

Answer (score 9):

Just use **app_offline.htm**, explained [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx).

If you want to keep the site down for a specific time period (or to some other external event, etc.) then you could run a (scheduled) script on the server to create or remove the `app_offline.htm` file when needed.

Comment: If it's best if you suggest redirect from asp.net itself

Answer (score 5):

`App_Offline.html` will do this.

Read about [App_Offline.html](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx) here.

Comment: I need a feature to redirect from my webpage. because I want to do some automatic time calcualtion for downtime. If then, redirect to maintanance web page

Answer (score 0):

If you can't deploy code to the production server, what about using a scheduled task batch file (or a custom program) to deploy and remove the [App_Offline.html](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx) file on a schedule?