# How do I add a delayed redirect to Django page?

Tags: python, django

I know it's fairly simple to add a redirect to `Django` with `HttpResponseRedirect`, but is it possible to make a delayed redirect?

What I want to add is like a confirmation page for the user that will basically say that "*Your request has been successful*" for 3 seconds and then be taken back to the login page or something.

I've read about `JQuery`, but as far as I know that's for `JavaScript` and I want to keep this as `Python` as possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you'll have to use javascript for it. For example, your django view returns a flag "redirect" in the context of a normal HttpResponse. Then, if flag exists, js counts to 3 and [redirects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript).

Comment: it's simple, on the page "successful" you add a meta html refresh with 3sec ; no javascript needed

Comment: I'm afraid this is not how HTTP is designed to work. Timing is an aspect of state which is not a feature of HTTP. Once a request is responded, the server is done. It doesn't keep tab of how long the request has been issued and issue another unless the client explicitly asked for it.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a `templateView` to display your "successful" page then in the template add

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://foobar.somewhereelse.com/">
```

Comment: Important! You need to place that inside block of content or this woldn't be worked: `{% extends "base.html" %}{% block content %}
<p>Success! Thank you for your message</p>
<p>After 5 seconds you will be redirected to the main page</p>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url={% url 'home' %}">
{% endblock %}`

Comment: Does the URL need to be a full rather than relative one? It seemed to in my case, and this feels consistent with how HTTP itself behaves with the Location: redirect header.

Comment: A fuller discussion of HTTP redirects can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411567/1048186).