# Can I redirect a local static html page to an online resource?

Tags: html, http-status-code-301, http-redirect, static-pages

I'm writing a small application extension and the only way to include some help is by a local, static html page (like `c:\program files\help.htm`). I can't use PHP for it. Is there any way to redirect such a page to an online page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect from .html page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-html-page)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure, you can use html meta tag to instruct the browser to redirect to another page. Put this in your `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

Related question: [How to redirect from .html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-html-page)

Comment: Thanks a million! And you're right, it's a duplicate. I Googled "redirect from local static html" but I didn't find an answer to my question like so.