# How do I redirect www.example.com/something?

Tags: php, html, web, webserver

I'd like to redirect a URL such as `www.example.com/something` to another site. I created a PHP script to do this, but in order for it to work I have to type in `www.example.com/something.php`.

I want to avoid users having to type in the `.php` or `.html` when accessing the redirected page. Would I have to create a directory on my webserver? And if so, what should I place in it?

I'm using a GoDaddy hosted Windows server (PHP Version 5, ASP.Net 2.0/3.0/3.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this meta tag in the head section of your HTML file:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.othersite.com">
```

See this StackOverflow question: [Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-an-html-page)

Alternatively you can use JavaScript to do this by placing the following in the head section of your HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = 'http://www.othersite.com';
</script>
```

*Note: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411574/2319844). I partially used it to improve this post.*

Comment: I tried this and it works. The problem is you have to enter `.html` at the end of the URL. I want to be able to just type `www.mysite.com/something`

Comment: @user63785 does the JavaScript solution allow you to do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need PHP for this.  Simply create a rewrite rule to do the redirection.  How you do this depends on your web server, which you didn't specify, so I'll leave the writing of the actual rule up to you.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to rewrite you url ,create a new file in  root directory   paste the following code in it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

and save it as .htaccess 
for more detail  you can check this link http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

to remove .html from url paste this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```