# How to redirect from one page to other without using server side programming?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?

I mean how can one program in client side script to  redirect browser from page1 to  page n?

Comment: http://bit.ly/OoBxma -- first link is to stack overflow with 4506 upvotes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-an-html-page This answer is even better since it's using HTML and you don't have to worry about the client disabling javascript

Comment: Who worries about a client disabling javascript?

Comment: @mccainz ,6% people disable javascript

Comment: I guess I'm just not in the space where those 6% are a concern. Are there stats on the browser breakout for that 6%?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
window.location="url";
```

The above should work