# Create custom page urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My link now is exp. http://example.com/index.php, how can I change this to exp. http://example.com/idex-home-page.html

Comment: Skill yourself up with `mod_rewrite`: http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in  .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule idex-home-page.html index.php
```

You should look at this beginners tutorial as well:

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right.

You are either trying to change your home page dir.
You dont want to get in htaccess stuff for this.

You can simply change your web server settings. Check documentation of your web server for that. For Apache this might be handy http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/sections.html

There is bunch of solutions for that. It might be a work around solution for your case probably but. in your index.php

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://example.com">
```

OR

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     window.location.href = "http://example.com"
  </script>
```

Taken from : [Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-an-html-page)