# How to redirect affiliate outbound links without PHP or htaccess?

Tags: redirect, seo, affiliate, outbound

I want to redirect outbound affiliate links and on this site there is no option for PHP or htaccess.

So far I've always done this using

```
<?php
header( 'Location:' ) ;
?>
```

but like I said this is not an option anymore as this site does not support php or .htaccess anymore.

Is there an alternative solution for this, using HTML ?

Comment: So when someone clicks into a page it will redirect to an external page after a few seconds or straight away?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect from an HTML page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-an-html-page)

Comment: I have a page where there are product reviews and affiliate links with each reviews. When user with click those links it will take him external page using our affiliate link. And there are lots of different links on same page, not just one.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code before `</head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://youraffiliatelink.com/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use this hrml code in header of your page :

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />`

or use JavaScript like this :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = "http://example.com"
    </script>
```

Comment: I am trying to redirect more than one affilite link on the page, and they are different.