# redirect in php in the middle of the site

Tags: php

I have a site in PHP; I want to redirect to external site after running some code; so I want something in the body tag; to redirect it after my code running; something like following example ; what can i do?

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
</header>
<?php
    $myffirend=" ";
$allmyffirend=" ";
$user=$_GET['user'];
    // this info save in my db

   redirect here // after save the information

   other code

?>
```

Comment: Check for using [Header location](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: why you need html code there

Comment: header("Location: ".$url); Make sure you don't send html before headers are sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want redirect after page load

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
   window.addEventListener("load", afterLoadRedirect, false);
} else {
   window.attachEvent('onload', afterLoadRedirect);
}

function afterLoadRedirect(){
  window.location='your url';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can inject javascript script with redirection:

```
echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.yourdomain.com'</script>";
```

Comment: You can't set headers after printing anything

Comment: That's true, my previous solution was wrong for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It's not posible to redirect using PHP after printing some code.
I suggest to move the code to the start of the file.
If this is not possible, you could do it using javascript:

```
window.location='your_url.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [`refresh` meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-an-html-page) (seconds, followed by destination):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/" />
```

The W3C recommends against using it for this purpose but I'm assuming you want to briefly show some sort of message before it changes. If not, stick with changing the `Location` header which must be done before any output:

```
header('Location: destination.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javaScript inside php:

```
echo '<script> window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";</script>';
```