# Redirect Not Found URLs of old m.domain.com to domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I had subdomain like m.domain.com and now I removed it and changed the website to responsive. Now I want to redirect all not found url's of m.domain.com to domain.com like below urls

```
m.domain.com/categoryname/post/ to domain.com/categoryname/post/
m.domain.com/category/categoryname/ to domain.com/category/categoryyname/post/ 
m.domain.com/tag/tagname/ to domain.com/tag/tagname/
```

Please somebody help me with rewriting rules for correct redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 404 page or 301 redirect or

```
<?php
// Permanent redirection
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.newdomain.com");
exit();
?>
```

write the above code in your previous subdoamin website page . for the location write your new address. first it will load to your previous domain then automatically return to new url you have written.

goto this page of yours m.domain.com/categoryname/post/ then write above code inside that page with location domain.com/categoryname/post/ .

Also check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-an-html-page).

Or you can also change it through your host.