# Apache redirect and prevent access

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following file system for my website which cannot be changed.

public_html

- css
- js
- .(other such folders)
- .
- vtu (<-The one I need to redirect to)

I need to ensure that all folders except 'vtu' cannot be accessed (and preferably should redirect to 'vtu'). And also, the home page

example.com should redirect to

example.com/vtu

Putting it in simple terms, if anything other than the vtu sub directory or its content(s) is requested for, there should be a redirect to example.com/vtu

I hope my problem has been expressed clearly enough.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-an-html-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^vlu(/.*)?$ /vlu [L,NC]
```

First 2 conditions avoid rewriting for real files and real directories.
`RewriteRule` has condition `!^vlu(/.*)$` which basically means don't rewrite if request is already for `vlu` or any of its sub directories. In the action part it just forwards to `/vlu`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Could you be a little more kind and explain those lines a little bit.

Comment: Make so much sense. Thank you :)

Comment: It does have one small flaw, it doesn't seem to redirect the home page.

Comment: It will rewrite home page also if you take out `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition.

Comment: I never thing to use `!`, +1 :)

Comment: Tanks @zx81, it comes handy as it saves one `RewriteCond`

Answer (score -1):

Just put this in your index.html in the **head** section..

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

or to not access your folders within your **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.com/.*$       [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.com$          [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.com/.*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(.*)$ http://www.example.com               [R,NC]
```

Comment: That would only redirect the user from the home page. What if, the user enters example.com/heShouldNotSeeThis ?