# How to create a URL which will direct to another domain?

Tags: web-services, http, web, hosting, forward

I have an ecommerce website. I have a help desk website hosted on another domain.

So what I want is to have an URL like this: "http://www.example.com/help" and it will take my customers to my help desk site which is hosted on another domain, let's say http://www.example2.com.

So when someone enters http://www.example.com/help" into their browser's address bar, they are taken to http://www.example2.com"

I think it should be fairly easy to achieve. Please point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the HTML of the web page you can paste a link like:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/help">Here you put text you want your customer to see</a>
```

If you want to redirect the customer to another URL, that question has been asked and answered here: [Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-an-html-page)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem. I know how to hyperlink. The thing is, I want to create an URL. Right now, "http://www.example.com/help" doesn't exist. I want to create this URL so that this URL redirects to some website of my liking.

Comment: Are you trying to create a sub folder called "/help" on your current domain, do you want to purchase another domain in addition to the one you already have, or do you want to link to the site of someone else?

Comment: I already have a site called www.example2.com
I want this URL: www.example1.com/help" to take me to www.example2.com

Sorry for my unclear explanation beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php for http://example.com/help page than you can simple paste following snippet to your help page

```
<?php header("Location: http://example2.com") ?>
```

this will redirect your user to example2.com directly!!

or you can use jquery in case you are not using php!!

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.location = "http://example2.com";    
    });
    </script>
```

Don't forget to add jquery library on header to get jquery working correctly,

hope this helps,

thanks.