# How do I redirect subdomain.example.com to subdomain.example.com/page in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, xampp

How do I redirect

For example if I entered subdomain.example.com in the search bar I hit enter and it redirected me to subdomain.example.com/page

How do I do that in .htaccess

This is what I have in .htaccess but it doesn't work:

```
#If Url is entered    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.example.com [NC]

#Redirect to    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.example.com/page/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-html-page

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess of subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine On

#If Url is entered
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subdomain.example.com
#Redirect to    
RewriteRule ^((?!page/).*)$ /page/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```