# Redirect to other view after timeout

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I´ve implemented a proxy with a listener with the next exception :

```
listeners: {
            exception: function () {
                Ext.Msg.alert(BB.Text.getText('ERROR_TIMEOUT_TITLE'), BB.Text.getText('ERROR_TIMEOUT_MSG') + '' + PROXY_TIMEOUT, Ext.emptyFn);
                Ext.redirectTo('http://www.google.es');  //for example
            }
        }
```

After the message I would like to redirect to other page / view but It is not working correctly

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Sencha Touch**

You probably want to read the documentation:

**Documentation**

```
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-method-redirectTo
```

**Quote**

> Redirects the browser to the given url. This only affects the url after the '#'.

Read the second part very carefully.
By the way this is *the same as*:

```
MyApp.app.redirectTo('http://www.google.es')
```

It take it from your post that you want to redirect to a different page inside a **webapp**.
Can be found ***[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-html-page)***

```
WebApp: window.location.href = "http://www.google.es"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below line would solve your purpose.

```
Ext.app.Application.redirectTo('http://www.google.es');
```

Comment: It isn´t working for me..  Thanks for your response @MadProgrammer