# How to redirect only Facebook traffic to another site

Tags: facebook, redirect, traffic

i want to redirect my site visitors to another site..
like i have create a link on Facebook group as www.1.com, when Facebook visitor click on that link and visiting my site then after some seconds they redirected to another site. is it possible.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, it is **bad**!

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

Replace "0" with the number of seconds before redirect.

Source: [Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page)

Comment: its redirect all traffic. i want to redirect only facebook visitors to other site...