# Auto-redirect to another HTML page

Tags: html

What is the syntax for making a page auto-redirect to a different HTML file in a separate folder? All of my searching returns how to redirect from one website to another.

Comment: It depends on what server tech you're dealing with and what your access to them is.  Are you using Apache and can you create a `RewriteRule` in an `.htaccess` file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page check this. Your question seems to be a duplicate of this.

Answer (score 81):

One of these will work...

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=http://example.com/'>
</head>
```

**...or it can done with JavaScript:**

```js
window.location.href = 'https://example.com/';
```

Comment: Window.open is a popup. I think window.location would be better?

Comment: What about security? In isolation, is there any problem with this? If so, is there any addition that can help? Also, is one option better than another?

Answer (score 23):

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">`

Answer (score 12):

If you're using Apache and can use a `.htaccess` file you should use the following type of redirect.  Add the following to an `.htaccess` file in the root of your website.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/oldfile_path/file_name\.html$ /oldfile_path/file_name.html [R=301,L]
```

This has the advantage of being a very fast and immediate redirect.  It also depends on your reason for the redirect.  This is a more permanent method because it sends the HTTP 301 status code signifying that the file has moved permanently and causes many browsers to cache that request.  You can change the code to something else like a 302 for temporary redirects.

Otherwise you can do a simple redirect using an HTML `<meta>` tag as suggested by others:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">
```

By default the `content="5"` makes that redirect after 5 seconds.  This will be slower and not all browsers support it.  A redirect can also be done in the server language of your choice `PHP`, `Node.js`, etc.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `<meta>` tag refresh, and `<meta>` tag in `<head>` section

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=your_url">
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to redirect your webpage to another HTML FILE, just use as followed:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content"2;otherpage.html">
```

2 being the seconds you want the client to wait before redirecting. Use `"url="` only when it's an URL, to redirect to an HTML file just write the name after the `';'`

Answer (score 4):

Its a late answer, but as I can see most of the people mentioned about "refresh" method to redirect a webpage. As per W3C, we should not use "refresh" to redirect. Because it could break the "back" button. Imagine that the user presses the "back" button, the refresh would work again, and the user would bounce forward. The user will most likely get very annoyed, and close the window, which is probably not what you, as the author of this page, want.

Use HTTP redirects instead. One can refer the complete documentation here: [W3C document](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback)

Answer (score 1):

I'm Maybe kind of late but here is a way to have a redirect for your website and another link if it does not do in auto redirect for them,

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=YOUR_URL_HERE" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.href = "site";
</script>
<title>Page Redirection</title>

<!-- Note: don't tell people to `click` the link, just tell them that it is a link. -->
If you are not redirected automatically, follow this <a href="/site">Link</a>
```