# How to use spring MVC to connect to other pages, with page hyperlink tags < href > or through the spring MVC framework

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How to use spring MVC to connect to other pages, with page hyperlink tags < href > or through the spring MVC framework, which way do you use it when dealing with similar issues?

it is such ，i am creating a WEB store with Spring mvc framework when i want from 'index.jsp' page connect to 'login.jsp'page,i did't know use tags or through the spring MVC framework,which is best? also i don't know the principle.
when i dealing it with framework but because there's a lot of connections in the page, if you go through the frame, you'll have a lot of controllers
i  think that there must be a good way to deal with similar questions but i don't know
Any help is greatly appreciated
spring mvc 中连接到其他页面是怎么处理，用页面超链接标签还是经过spring mvc框架处理，在处理类似问题的时候你用的是哪一种方式呢？

Comment: Stay with english here. Most of us can't read chinese(?).

Answer (score 0):

I would google. Then you'll find pages like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27895443/3959856

In a Spring controller you do this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public String redirect() {    
    return "redirect:login";
}
```

What is best? Not sure, maybe the linked example is faster because you don't have to go through the server.

Comment: I don't know how to express my meaning,the same question ,everyone's express is different

Comment: I know that is simple and quick but i afraid that will meet with  trouble in future when maintenance

Comment: what do you by trouble?

Comment: maybe sometimes meet with trouble ,I don't know whether this is processed by server or hyperlinked,maybe i think too much ,deal with it when i meet with it.