# Doxygen output, how to make index file at the same level of html folder

Tags: doxygen

In Doxygen output, the index.html is in html foleder, which is not easy for customer to find.

how can I configure so that index is at the same level of html folder, example as below:
doxygen_output/html/*.*
doxygen_output/index.html

or if this is not possible,below structure is also fine:
in html folder, move all files except for index in a new folder.
doxygen_output/html/newfolder/*.*
doxygen_output/html/index.html

my target is to make index.html obviouse for customer to click.
thanks for your support, I will wait online

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in doxygen. The only thing you could do is to create an own index.html at the place you want want and make an automatic redirect from there.

See e.g. [Auto-redirect to another HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895424/auto-redirect-to-another-html-page)

Or search stack overflow / the net for "html auto redirect" and similar.

Comment: Hi Albert, thanks for your suggestion and.I will test it tomorrow.