# How to create a master html file above the output directory from rmarkdown::render_site

Tags: html, r-markdown

When using `rmarkdown::render_site`, it render all the HTMLs into the same directory.

Is it possible to create a master html file? When opening, it will directly link to the index.html in the output directory?

The reason to do this is because the output directory contains too much HTMLs and css files that are too messy to find the index file for regular user.

```
_Master.html # try to create this file
├──(output directory)
├── Index.html
├── Data1.html
└── Data2.html
```

---

### Update

Found a way to do it in other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895424/auto-redirect-to-another-html-page). Create a html file that will redirect to the desired html once loaded.

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=your_url">
```

Comment: Usually the `index.rmd` file is the master file, which tells Rmarkdown how to render the files, you can also look into the `_output.yml` file, which controls output directory of the files.