# Redirect github page to different url

Tags: git, github-pages

I have changed my repo from **foo** to **bar** . So automatically the github page url changed from **/foo** to **/bar** but i want that **/foo** also redirects to **/bar.** How can I achieve this ?

I am using a custom domain but I don't think that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems GitHub [doesn't redirect the pages](https://github.com/blog/1508-repository-redirects-are-here) when renaming repository:

> GitHub Pages sites are not automatically redirected when their
> repositories are renamed at this time.

I think you can still make a redirect by adding a page to your [ritz078.github.io](https://github.com/ritz078/ritz078.github.io) project. Create `embed-js.html` with:

```html
---
permalink: /embed-js/
---

<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<link rel=canonical href="http://rkritesh.in/embed.js/index.html">
<meta http-equiv=refresh content="0; url=http://rkritesh.in/embed.js/index.html">
```

Comment: Mine is a normal static website. How do I convert it to this. I have already done what's written https://github.com/ritz078/embed.js/tree/gh-pages . What else should I do ? My old repo name was **embed-js** . Now it is **embed.js**

Comment: Actually redirect works, http://rkritesh.in/embed.js/embed-js -> http://rkritesh.in/embed.js Try `redirect_from: "/../embed-js"`.

Comment: Got a reply from github that this feature is currently not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Recreate an `embed-js` repository

In the `gh-pages branch` add an `index.html` file that contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://rkritesh.in/embed.js/">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "http://rkritesh.in/embed.js/"
        </script>
        <title>Page Redirection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Note: don't tell people to `click` the link, just tell them that it is a link. -->
        If you are not redirected automatically, follow the <a href='http://rkritesh.in/embed.js/'>link to example</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

But this will only redirect the traffic from `http://rkritesh.in/embed-js/` other page like `http://rkritesh.in/embed-js/anypage/` will get a 404 error.

reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411601/1548376