# Why opening a product page in eBay redirects to a different URL?

Tags: javascript, html, url, web

When I open the following url in browser,
http://pages.ebay.com/link/?nav=item.view&id=141628727383&alt=web

It redirects to a different url
http://www.ebay.com/itm/141628727383

What's the mechanism?

Comment: It's called ....... wait for it ........ URL rewriting

Comment: May be they are usnig <meta> tag  in head...Ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it uses some kind of JS redirection:

```js
var eULin;
window.onload = function() {
    eULin = new eUL();
    eULin.version = '1.4.1+1424198141014';
    eULin.redirect();
}
```

`eUL` is defined in http://pages.ebay.com/link/univlink.min.js

`eUL.prototype.redirect` calls `eUL.prototype.winRedirect`, which calls [`location.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace). That replaces the current page with a new one, in a way that the current one won't be accessible using the back button.

Comment: I am using jsoup to retrieve the content of the website. Is there a way to detect url that uses such kind of redirect technique and retrieve the redirected url?