# How do I configure my subdomain to point to a wordpress blog in AWS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain

I just setup my wordpress blog using this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbQSs-_d-yM

Which I ended up having a wordpress site with this address XX.XX.XXX.XXX/blog

I want to have use a subdomain to direct to that part of the site. I was able to create a record set (AWS Route 53) to be able to point to the IP, but when I go to the subdomain it would show me the Apache page which is what you see when you go to the IP address (XX.XX.XXX.XXX). My domain name btw is being used by a .Net web app which is hosted in a windows server.

With that said, how do I go about making sure that the subdomain is pointed to the address XX.XX.XXX.XXX/blog instead of the XX.XX.XXX.XXX address?

I'm not really familiar with DNS setup so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

DNS resolution will only return an IP address. It is not possible to resolve a DNS name to a URL such as `X.X.X.X/blog`.

You could edit the default page returned by the web server (`index.htm` for Apache, `default.html` for IIS) to [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page) to the `/blog` page.

Comment: Is that the 301 redirect that one of them recommended?