# How to refresh a page and redirect to another page using header() function in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am able to refresh a page using normal PHP.
How do I do this with CodeIgniter?

I was trying this in PHP:

```
<html>
<title>Thank You</title>
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
  <center>
    <h1>Thank You For Visiting...Wish you to visit again...</h1>
  </center>
  <?php
    header(refresh:5; url="login_input.php");
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I know to I have to write this:

```
"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/welcome/"
```

But where?

Do I have to create functions in model and controller to do this?

Comment: The header function can only be utilized prior to loading ANY content on a page. So your original script should not even work. That said, codeigniter has a great `redirect` function https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: In the name of all that's holy get rid of those `<br><br> etc`

Comment: @CollinD: my guess is that it works because of some caching server-side that delays the sending of the actual content.

Comment: Oh yes, there are plenty of reasons that could work depending on PHP/webserver settings. But it's just really really bad practice, I suppose.

Comment: You can't use PHP to perform the re-direct if you wish to display page content, instead use PHP to generate the re-direct URL (If required) and use a HTML re-direct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page

Comment: @CollinD docs can be found here now at codeigniter main website https://codeigniter.com/docs Both versions

Comment: Oh fancy that. Thanks wolfgang good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for replying...And many thanks to Mr. Dan Belden for providing the link to gather knowledge.

Actually the desired code which I was looking for is as follows...

```
<html>
<title>Thank You</title>
<head>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="5; url=<?php echo    
base_url();?>index.php/welcome/login">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<center><h1>Thank You For Visiting...Wish you to visit again.......  
</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```