# Redirect to URL in HTML

Tags: html, redirect

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with HTML and Javascript. All I want is a small app which has nothing to do but a redirect to an existing website www.mysite.com.

A tried with the meta-tag as described in [Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page) and with an iframe, both didn't work, means nothing happened. Please help.

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:scroll !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important">
    <iframe src="ariva.de"; scrolling="yes" style="width:100%;height:100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your working: the source of your HTML that does not work. Also, are you using VS2015 as anything more than a text editor? If not then that is an unhelpful tag.

Answer (score 0):

Per Your Question:

> All I want is a small app which has nothing to do but a redirect to an existing website www.mysite.com.

This can actually be achieved with one line of javascript on your page:

```
document.location.replace('http://www.ariva.de/');
```

The Location.replace() method replaces the current resource with the one at the provided URL.

[DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work in an app:
"APPHOST9624: The app can't use script to load the <URL_HERE> url because the url launches another app. Only direct user interaction can launch another app."