# anchor tag with href as other than http is not working while sending mail to gmail

Tags: email, gmail

I am using the smtp sendmail function, in the anchor `<a>` tag `href` attribute we have reference other than `http://` ie something like below

```
transauth://some other data
```

but the gmail is not creating the **hyperlink** of `transauth` but creating of `http://gmail.com` ,Any solutions regarding this.

Comment: take a look at this website: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/11/the-trouble-with-anchor-links-in-email-newsletters/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail strips links that use custom uri schemas.

A work around however is that if you have a website somewhere you can host a simple redirect page that will redirect you to the correct schema.

This is a pretty bullet proof redirect here I copied from [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page#5411601)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://example.com">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "http://example.com"
        </script>
        <title>Page Redirection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Note: don't tell people to `click` the link, just tell them that it is a link. -->
        If you are not redirected automatically, follow the <a href='http://example.com'>link to example</a>
    </body>
</html>
```