# Trying to redirect the pages of my tumblr pages

Tags: html, redirect, web, tumblr

Alright I am trying to do a website for my sisters hairdressing business. I am using tumblr and weebly. Right so I am trying to create pages and have them directed to a weebly page for like a gallery or the about me and other things. Issue is no redirect shows under page format. I was wondering if I can stick a html code somewhere that can redirect each page to each of my weebly pages its meant for.

Comment: So yeah I don't want the front page link to change but I want each of my page links to go to a web page of my choice

Answer (score 1):

Tumblr allows you to set pages as redirects. Blog settings > Edit theme > Add a page, then change the `Standard Layout` dropdown to `Redirect`.

[image: Screenshot of the Add a page menu in Tumblr]

You can then add in the URL/redirect you want.

Or if that's not what you're trying to achieve, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411574/6455891) shows some HTML solutions.

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't show for me the redirect page only two, like I said before only custom and standard. I tried reverificating email like some says fixes it but that doesn't work either.

Comment: IIRC, redirect are added after the blog has existed for a set amount of time. How long, no idea as it isn't documented. I would suggest contacting Tumblr Support.