# How To Redirect URL to specific Website File

Tags: apache, redirect, server

What would be the best way(and how would I) redirect a url such as :
www.samplesite.com/support

To an actual file :
www.samplesite.com/support.htm

Answer (score 0):

Create a file inside `support` called `index.html` with this inside

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=www.samplesite.com/support.htm/" />
```

This way, when the user goes to www.samplesite.com/support.htm the meta refresh will redirect him to the desired file: `support.htm`

**@NinethSense says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page)**

> Use of meta refresh is discouraged by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C). Ref: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh. So it is recommended to use server redirect instead.