# Go to another site automatically

Tags: html

How can I make a Web page that takes me automatically without clicking to another site? (I use in HTML)

I tried to find a answer but I didn't find any answer that it in HTML.

I tried to write like this:

```html
<a href="http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/">

</a>
```

but this not take me automatically.

can someone help me?
thanks!

Comment: You can't with only HTML afaik. You'll almost definitely need JS.

Comment: [Not true](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5411567/542251) @Carcigenicate.. though this is discouraged if you read the comments

Comment: I can't with only HTML? sure?

Comment: @Liam Seems to discourage the use of JS since mobiles may have JS turned off. That was 4 years ago though. It wouldn't surprise me if most mobiles have JS enabled now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this in the `head` section of the HTML document.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=randomname.com" />
```

As soon as the page loads, on 0 seconds, you can go to your page.