# Hide the catalog page on Shopify

Tags: e-commerce, shopify

Is there a way to hide the catalog page in Shopify? [Here is more detail about the Shopify catalog page.](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/collections/change-catalog-page)

Comment: Shopiy provides url redirects on the server side. Check URL redirects under Navigation inside Shopify dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might add an automatic javascript redirection to home when collection URL contains 'all'.

So this could be something like this in collection template in your theme :

```
{% if collection.handle == 'all' %}
    <script>window.location.href = '{{ shop.url }}';</script>
{% else %}
    Usual code for collection template display if this is not the 'all' collection.
{% endif %}
```

Please note that is NOT RECOMMENDED practice.
For example, if your customer has disabled Javascript, the page content will be blank as redirection won't work.

A better practice would be to not index page in search engines, so if there is no internal link and if search engines do not index it, no one will see it.

To do that, open the 'theme.liquid' template, and then, add this in `<head>` section :

```
{% if collection.handle == 'all' %}
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
{% endif %}
```

HTH

Comment: I feel like this is the best solution given the inability to remove /collections/all. Thank you!

Comment: This actually is a bad solution. Even in terms of SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please give us a little more details about what you want ? If you want to remove the catalog from main menu , you need to go to Online store > navigation > find the main menu and remove catalog from there. That will remove the menu named catalog from your theme.

https://help.shopify.com/manual/sell-online/online-store/menus-and-links

If you donot want to show any product in the catalog page, you need to go to Online store > themes > edit html/css of the active theme and modify the collection.liquid to remove the section that displays the products.

Give us more details so that we can help you properly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have already removed the page from the navigation. I understand that you can edit the look/feel in the HTML/CSS of this page as well. That is not what I am hoping to accomplish. I want this page to be removed entirely. When a user visits /collections/all, even if the URL is removed from the navigation, the page still exists. I do not want to edit the look/feel of the page, I want to create functionality that makes this URL unable to be navigated to.

Comment: well , shopify has a redirect manager, I just tried to use that to redirect /collections/all to anywhere else. It did not worked.

what you can do is to use javascript to redirect that page to homepage or anywhere else.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
</script>`

Comment: You need to put the code above in the collection.liquid file.

Comment: Agreed. I believe a redirect is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you provided:

> All Shopify stores have a page at the URL `your-store.com/collections/all` *that lists all of the visible products in the store.* This is the store's catalog page. By default, products on the catalog page are shown in alphabetic order. You can create a collection to control the order in which your products are shown on this page.

If you want to hide / remove that page altogether, you need to do a few things:

1. Create a collection to control your catalog page, [as described via that same link](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/collections/change-catalog-page#create-a-collection-to-control-your-catalog-page),
2. Redirect it so that anyone that visits the page gets taken somewhere else e.g. your homepage. You can use the snippet below, based on [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411601/1284913) for "Redirect[ing] from an HTML page" [or, in this case, a Liquid template:]

```
{%- layout none -%}
{%- assign title = "Nothing to See Here!" -%}
{%- assign url = shop.url -%}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  {%- include 'head-meta' -%}
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url={{ url }}">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.top.location.href = "{{ url }}"
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>{{ page_title }}</h1>
  <p>If you are not redirected automatically, follow the <a href="{ url }}">link</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

3. Remove it from the sitemap. You can do that (for this Collection or any Shopify resource) [using my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53081910/how-to-add-noindex-for-specific-page-in-shopify-store/58813104#58813104) — **tl;dr** add a metafield.seo.hidden with value `1`.