# Redirect to previous page when refresh current page url

Tags: asp.net

I have one scenario where user submit one form. After submit form it redirect to the confirmation page. I need here that when user refresh url or press Ctrl+f5 or press F5 or click on browser refresh button this page again redirect to the previous form page where submission has happend.
I tried this code:

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

but it is redirecting without refresh url.
Need Help

Answer (score 0):

The code above will simply redirect to "http://example.com/" whenever the confirmation page is loaded. See this:

[Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page/5411567)

What you can do is save some count in Session and increment it when the confirmation page loads. Then check if its 1 return the confirmation page view if its >1 which will be the case if someone refreshes it. In that case you can redirect to form page.

Comment: Hi Hamza, Currently i am not using any session. I need here in anytime on confirmation page it should redirect to the form page. if it can be possbile through jquery also that would b e good for me.

Comment: Have u tried using "TempData" to save the counter because TempData values also persist the redirects as apposed to ViewData or ViewBag?

Comment: currently i am using asp.net not mvc