# Redirect subdomain to external website with query parameters, without .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I'm helping out a charity with a website hosted on Wordpress.com. They use a 3rd party website to collect donations. They want to use a subdomain as a permalink to their page on the 3rd party site so they can change it in the future. As far as I can tell, Wordpress.com doesn't offer htaccess or equivalent.

So how do I make subdomain.website.com redirect to externalsite.com?foo=bar ?

Answer (score 0):

If your on an Apache server then you can use .htaccess on desired directories.  A lot of Wordpress security plugins like Ithemes use the .htaccess when their on Apache which is probably most of the time.

Comment: As I said, as far as I know you can't use htaccess with hosting on wordpress.com.

Comment: I need to pay more attention when I'm reading the questions.  Sorry I didn't realize you are on Wordpress.com.  Yes, that's a multi site setup. Perhaps it's time for them the move their site to standard linux hosting.  Godaddy has a sale right now - 12 months for $12.

Comment: That's a possibility. Was hoping for an easier solution, though.

Comment: I just Googled this and here's another stackoverflow link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page  It's a bit of an old school approach but it might work if you can stick in the header page somewhere.