# Redirecting to Social Media Page from a Child URL

Tags: html, url

I have my website up recently and I have seen some sites and advertisements where they redirect to their Social Media Pages from the site itself.

Ex:

- mysite.com/facebook should redirect to facebook.com/mysitesfbpage
- mysite.com/twitter should redirect to twitter.com/mysitestwitterpage

How do you do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use meta tags

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411567/3649914) for the OP

I consider you [read up](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) about meta tags

Comment: Thank you Joshua. I actually managed to do it with the htaccess file. But thanks for this as well. Learnt a lot more.