# Redirect from http:// to https://

Tags: javascript, html, security, redirect, web

I want to redirect users from my http website to https site is there like a meta or JavaScript or html to do this my site has a http server as well as a secure version.

Comment: Redirects are best done at the HTTP level. How you implement them depends on your HTTP server and/or choice of server side programming language.

Comment: I liked both answers but Javascript was better for me , thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a quick-fix you can do it like this:

```
if(window.location.protocol != 'https:') {
  location.href =   location.href.replace("http://", "https://");
}
```

But I recommend you to do it using the available method in your web server

Comment: Thank you that also worked and is easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411601/5031164

You should use **html meta** tag for newer browsers AND a **javascript** script for the older one, at the same time:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://example.com/" />
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.location.href = "https://example.com"
</script>
```

I also report:

> For completeness, I think the best way, if possible, is to use server redirects, so send a 301 status code [[...]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411601/5031164)

Comment: What "newer browsers" do you mean? Which "older browser" wouldn't work with it?

Comment: Very old browser like till IE6 could have problem ( [read more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) ). Anyway I read that browsers could ignore 0 value meta refresh in few circumstances, so I suggest to keep the js script as well. [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page/5411601#5411601)