# How to redirect HTTP to HTTPS with Sails/React?

Tags: reactjs, http, redirect, https, sails.js

**Current state:** Depending on the `npm start` script, my web app is accessible by at the `http://` address, or the `https://` address, but not both.

**Goal:** I'd like the app to run on `https://`, and for any `http://` requests to be redirected to `https://`.

**App info:** The web app is created with Sails for the server, and `create-react-app` for the UI. To run locally, I use two terminals to start each up (server on `:1337`, UI on `:3000`). To run in prod, I build the UI and copy the build into the server folder, then start the server on `:84` (`:80` already taken).

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried adding redirection on the Sails server by adding [middleware and policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450940/automatic-https-connection-redirect-with-node-js-express).
- I've tried adding redirection on the UI by adding [a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344452/redirect-from-http-to-https) in the HTML header, checking for `window.location.protocol` in `index.js`, adding to the [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware), and using [react-https-redirect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-https-redirect).

In all cases, I'm able to access the app if I go to the `https://` address, but get `err_empty_response` from the `http://` one. *None of my `http://` requests seem to even reach the app or server.*

I've heard that using NGINX as a load-balancer may solve this, but I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't require as much set up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you set a redirect on your http web server so that all http requests go through https. Then you can remove your javascript middleware/redirects so that the http redirects are handled by the web server first (you could still have sails middleware/policies as a second layer).

Comment: @Anthony, by web server do you mean the react UI, or the sails server? How can I get either of them to listen for http requests? Only https requests seem to be reaching them.

Comment: Gave up trying to have port :84 serve both HTTP and HTTPS requests. Changed main port to be :94 serving HTTPS, and added a listener on :84 to redirect to :94.