# Redirect URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

is it possible to redirect the hostname of the URL using javascript?

If URL contains "content/articles", it should remain in the same URL. Otherwise, it should redirect all other URLs from www to www1.

I think i got the **"/content/articles"** part but **window.location.replace** doesnt seem to work.

For example:

- https://www.abc.com.sg/content/articles will remain the same URL.
- https://www.abc.com.sg redirect to https://www1.abc.com.sg

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {
         if (window.location.href.indexOf("/content/articles") > -1) {
          // Do not redirect                                
         } else {
   // Redirect from www to www1
   window.location.replace(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname.replace("www", "www1")+window.location.pathname);
  }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try `window.location.href.replace()` ?

Comment: would be smarter to do this server side. Also no point waiting for window to load either

Comment: @charlietfl yea.. but my client's requirement is to do it via javascript :(

Comment: There is another way to refresh @user3188291 Meta Refresh Redirect https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411567/713789

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `window.location.href.replace()`

```js
let url = window.location.href.replace('://www','://www1')
console.log(url);
```

Here is the example

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {
         if (window.location.href.indexOf("/content/articles") > -1) {
          // Do not redirect                                
         } else {
   // Redirect from www to www1
   window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('://www','://www1');
  }
        }
</script>
```

`replace('://www','://www1')` Also fine since it replace only first occurrence

Comment: Hi. thanks for your reply. Just in case the URL contains www at the path name, im afraid it would replace it as well. Example: www.abc.com.sg/testwww.html would be redirected www1.abc.com.sg/testwww1.html. Is it possible to just limiting it to the hostname?

Comment: But it `replace(str,str)` replaces first occurrence only

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so i am posting it here the answer by @shalitha is correct and there won't be any issue with the replace because with replace only the very first instance is replaced. If you want to replace all the instances then you need to add g ( global) to it, which we don't want here.
Details - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp