# Redirect old Joomla php page roots to new index.html page

Tags: php, html, http-redirect, migrate

I created a new homepage for our company. The old page had good goodle search results, but now these pages gives the 404 not found message after clicking on it. It would be very important to redirect visitors to our new page.

The old page was Joomla based, so it had an index.php and had subfolders in page addresses like 'index.php/en/production'.

The new page I created instead is an html5 page with css and Javascript and it opens with index.html I want to redirect every old roots to.

How can I achive this? Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page)

Comment: OK, I have checked the other related questions, but could not find the solution. The one you mention has this accepted answer:
"

Try using:

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />

Note: Place it in the head section.

Additionally for older browsers if you add a quick link in case it doesn't refresh correctly:

<p><a href="http://example.com/">Redirect</a></p>

Will appear as

Redirect

This will still allow you to get to where you're going with an additional click."

Comment: Is example.com the old site or the new site? Should I write 'index.php/en/production' to the place of example.com?

Comment: It is absolutely not clear how to achieve what I mentioned in my question, so instead of redirecting me to another question that not answers my question I would be absolutely thankful if somebody can tell me what to do. Than you!