# From Newsletter thank you form - what HTML code can I add to make sure the <a href="http://mywebsite.com"> refreshes?

Tags: html, css

I have just created a Newsletter Form on my website, via an external provider called "Benchmark" - to save time because I am not a professional programmer, so I only know HTML and CSS coding so far.

Their service generates an automatic thank you page that I am free to use, but when you click "back to the website", it automatically goes back to the cached page, which means that all the data inserted into the Newsletter form (email and name) is still there.

I think this gives the customers a lot of uncertainty about whether their data has gone through (and Benchmark replied that I had to make my own "Thank You" page if I want this function), so I would like to create my own page with a link (using HTML-code), which will automatically refresh the page that is linked back to - so that the customer comes back to the page with an empty Newsletter Form.

I have seen some similar questions with answers in the Forum, but as far as I could see, they use other programming languages that I don't know how to implement, so if anybody knows of a method of how to do this with HTML (and CSS, if needed), I would be very grateful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: jesus christ this is so hard to read

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I am sorry, I tried to be as clear and concise as possible, I know the guidelines for this website. I also inserted several line-breaks for adding readability (it is just the second time I use this forum, and I forgot they get deleted when you submit the form).

Comment: I will try to shorten: Is there a HTML code I can add to the <a href="">, so that the page the inserted URL links to, is automatically refreshed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect from a HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-a-html-page)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a page that will redirect to your newsletter form (with the fields empty). You have a couple of options: use a bit of javascript, or use an HTML meta tag. For both of these you'll need a new page. Since you want a pure HTML answer, I'll show you the meta tag version first.

For the meta tag, you'll simply want to put the following code in the head section of your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

The javascript solution would also go in the head section as a `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "http://example.com/";</script>
```

In either one, just replace `http://example.com/` with the address of your newsletter form and you should be good to go.

There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page) that you can look at if you want to learn more.

Comment: I will try the HTML meta tag for my page then (but I am assuming with the extra " in front of "http://"?). And just to make sure that I have understood you correctly: I add the meta tag on the web page that contains the link? Thank you so much for your help so far :-)!

Comment: @Azita Yep, the meta tag goes on the page that contains the link :)

The quotation marks belong to the `content` attribute of the `meta` tag and not to the `url=` part, so no extra `"` infront of the `http://`, just like `content="0; url=http://example.com/"` :)