# Firebase Hosting - How to redirect domain to url (.pl to .com/pl)

Tags: firebase-hosting

I'm using Firebase Hosting. I own two domains:
**mydomain.com** and **mydomain.pl** (polish version)

I would like to redirect **mydomain.pl** to **mydomain.com/pl** (this is how I manage website translations).

In Firebase Hosting configuration I can only redirect **mydomain.pl** to **mydomain.com**. If I enter mydomain.com/pl error message is shown: "Enter a valid domain (not a URL)".

Website is served using https.

Comment: I think this has the answer to your question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page>

Comment: @AlexTrix Which answer are you reffering to? Under provided link there are lots of hacks using javascript. I'm not sure this is the best way to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting with firebase hosting, create an index.html file for yourdomain.pl and then use javascript to redirect. You don't need any content at all in the index.html file just your redirect. You can use this code:

```
<script>
window.location = "https://yourdomain.com/pl";
<script>
```

Let me know if you need any help.