# Redirecting multiple webpages on GitHub Pages

Tags: redirect, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-extensions

I read GitHub pages [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.14/user/articles/redirects-on-github-pages) for enabling redirects on GitHub Pages using the `jekyll-redirect-from` plugin. I was able to redirect from one page to another, but I have some  different requirements. I need to redirect all pages from a starting url to another.

These URLs

- `www.example.com/abc/def`
- `www.example.com/abc/xyz`

should be redirected to

- `www.example.com`

Answer (score 2):

As [stated in the documentation for the plugin](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from#usage), you can add specify multiple urls for the `redirect_from` key.

For example create a `index.md` file with:

```
---
title: index
redirect_from:
  - /abc/def/
  - /abc/xyz/
---

## Hello, world!
```

and a `_config.yml` with:

```yaml
title: Redirection test

markdown: kramdown
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-redirect-from
```

Now both `/abc/def` and `/abc/xyz` will redirect to your index page.

Comment: I need to redirect a family of urls not just two.

Comment: @TheOneAboveAll You mean redirection all urls, that start with `/abc/*` ?

Comment: Yes, I want to achieve redirection for a url pattern @kalehmann

Comment: @TheOneAboveAll As far as I know, this is not possible using Jekyll and GitHub pages. The closest you could achieve with GitHub pages would be [creating a custom 404 page](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site) with [a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page). This would allow you to redirect all nonexisting pages to one page of your choice.