# html change to next site

Tags: html, web, video

I am currently working on a homepage for myself.

My idea is to use our intro video as intro for the website. After its finished i want so switch to home.html

thats my curent index.html:

```
<body>
<video id="introVideo" autoplay muted>
    <source src="images/logo.webm">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>

      <script>
      var vid = document.getElementById("introVideo");
      vid.onended = function() {
        alert("The video has ended");
      };
      </script>
```

The alert is working, i am searching a funtion to switch to home.html now.

ty for your help.

Comment: Sorry, what does this have to do with Java?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page)

Comment: window.location = "home.html"