# save button to work automatically taking you straight back to the home page

Tags: html

I have also added as save button " Save  " and I have also added "Homepage.html" so that once everything has been saved it would automatically take you straight back to the page but the problem is that I dont know how to get the save button to work so that once you have completed all of your details including a photo you have chosen it would save automatically.

```
                <!-- Profile info-->
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <form action="/action_page.php" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
                            <div class="container">
                                
                                <input type="text" placeholder="First name" name="First name" required>
                                
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Second name" name="Second name" required>
                                
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Email address" name="email address" required>
                                
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Old password" name="Oldpsw" required>
                                
                                <input type="password" placeholder="New password" name="Newpsw" required>
                                
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>
                                
                                
                
                                <!--save button-->
                                
                                <div class="clearfix">
                                    <button type="submit" a href="HomePage.html" class="Savebtn"> Save </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        
                         <!--save button-->
                  
                <!--Profile-->
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from an HTML page, use the META Tag. With this, use the http-equiv attribute to provide an HTTP header for the value of the content attribute. The value in the content is the number of seconds; you want the page to redirect after.

Set the content attribute to 0, if you want it to load immediately.
eg:`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />`

for more info check this out:[Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page)

Comment: in other words change this line from this "<button type="submit" a href="HomePage.html" class="Savebtn"> Save </button>" to this "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />" i tested it and it did take me straight back to my home page would when i put my details onto profile info would it save automatically aswell?

Comment: @blueviolet didn't get it are you trying to say you want to save data using html?

Comment: it does not matter what way as long as when you enter all of your details it would save and take you straight to the home page :)