# configure a searchable keyword in the browser's address bar to my website's url

Tags: html, url, keyword, shortcut

How can i can create a shortcut for my website's URL ?
for example if i type in **test123**
in my browser's address bar it will open the website **test123.com/apps/home**.
Is there a way to do this configuration from my html ?
I tried adding Description and keywords meta in the header tag, but didn't do the trick for me

```
<head>
        <title>test123</title>
        <meta name="description" content="test123">
        <meta name="keywords" content="test123">
</head>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a "shortcut" just for you, or for everyone on the internet?

Comment: for everyone, that's why im trying to implement it in my html code

Comment: You could set something up so that **test123.com** redirects to **test123.com/apps/home**, and there are several different ways you can do that. It is not possible to redirect from  **test123** to **test123.com/apps/home**, because **test123** is not a valid [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL).

Comment: okay how can i let test123.com or test123/ redirects to the full URL ?

Comment: Are you looking only for an HTML solution? If so, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page.

Comment: actually in this solution the parameter i pass  will be my destination URL. what i need is to pass a parameter that will redirect me to the final URL