# How to redirect a url to a different url in html

Tags: html, url, redirect

I want to redirect my old domain url to a new domain url

For example  :
[www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) (old url ) to [www.examole.com](http://www.examole.com) (new url)

So i want to redirect my old url to new URL

Note: I don't have cpanel i have hosted my site in github and my domain is from freedom (a free domain)

Answer (score 0):

> There are a couple of ways to redirect to another webpage with
> **JavaScript**. The most popular ones are `location.href` and `location.replace`

```
window.location.href = "http://www.examole.com";
```

**OR**

```
window.location.replace("http://www.examole.com");
```

---

> Simply use a meta `http-equiv` tag to "refresh" the page to a new url
> as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.examole.com">
```

The **content** sets how long to wait until to redirect the user, and the **url** sets where to redirect the user.

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of methods to get this done, so, If I asume that you dont have access to host panel to make a redirect in cpanel or any other host manager, you can do this:

Create a new file, or replace index.php, index.htm or index.html code for this one

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv=Refresh content="0; URL=http://your-new.site"> 
<title>Your site</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <title>Redirecting</title>
</head>

<body>
 Redirecting to the new site...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Repost from here: [Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page)

but,

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```