# Redirecting without clicking

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can i make redirect without clicking.

i want to do it automatically

```
<script>
    $("#Div3").click(function(){

    window.location.replace("http://your.next.page/");

});

</script>
```

Comment: Do you know what `$("#Div3").click(function(){`…`});` does?

Comment: If your goal is to send the user off to another page when they visit a specific page, an HTTP redirect may be more appropriate. Skips the resource use of loading up a page and its assets.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `$(document).ready()` [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). But Joseph is right, a HTTP redirect sounds more appropriate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect as soon as the page is loaded, you can use

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    window.location.replace("http://your.next.page/");
});
```

or you can use `window.location.href` to simulate a mouse click, whereas `.replace` simulates a HTTP redirect from the server, if that matters to you.

Answer (score 1):

you can add in the header :

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv = "refresh" content = "3; url = http://your.next.page/" />
</head>
```

[source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-automatically-redirect-a-Web-Page-to-another-URL)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.replace("http://your.next.page/");`
directly so that the page is reloaded as soon as the javascript code is read.