# How can I give a button more than one location?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this button for logging in to my website that is linked to a function in my javascript. But how can I also set the location to direct to another html page after logging in?

```html
<div id="button_container">
          <button onclick="login()">Login</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting the button to go to another page after being clicked? If so then it needs to be included in the Javascript. window.location can be used to redirect to another page if this is what your question is asking.

Comment: what is your backend for authenticate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page

Comment: @Lee Hi I am using firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to `login()`

```
window.location.href = 'login.html';
```

Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage) for more info

Comment: Thanks David for your help! This worked for me.