# 301 redirect for site hosted at github?

Tags: redirect, github, hosting, jekyll, github-pages

Here's a Github repository of mine: https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs

There's a `gh-pages` branch to hold the project documentation, which is basically the project website: https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/tree/gh-pages

This branch setups the documentation site at http://n1k0.github.com/casperjs/ — hurray.

In the meanwhile, I've bough the `casperjs.org` domain to get this website available through it, so I put a `CNAME` file as [recommended in the docs](http://pages.github.com/#custom_domains): https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/gh-pages/CNAME — in their example, the operation is supposed to *create redirects from www.example.com and charlie.github.com to example.com*…

While the website now points to http://casperjs.org/, there's no 301 redirect from http://n1k0.github.com/casperjs/ (the old site url) to the new domain name.

Any idea how to setup such a redirect, if it's even possible? Is it a bug? If it is, where should I open an issue?

Comment: +1. I'd also rather my page was _only_ accessible through the domain name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permanent redirect from Github gh-pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302663/permanent-redirect-from-github-gh-pages)

Comment: ah, I swear I've been thoroughly searching before asking, I'm sorry :$ Edit: quite not the same question actually, and some insightful comments have been posted below methinks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best approach for redirection of old pages in Jekyll and GitHub Pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178304/what-is-the-best-approach-for-redirection-of-old-pages-in-jekyll-and-github-page)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Bringing this topic back from the dead to mention that GH now supports redirect-from's redirect-to parameter https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from#redirect-to

Simply add this to your _config.yml

```
gems:
  - jekyll-redirect-from
```

And this to the top of your index page.

```
---
redirect_to: "http://example.com"
---
```

Comment: Good solution, but it's worth pointing out that this gem creates an html page with a meta refresh redirect, rather than an http-level redirect.

Comment: There is a recently fixed serious default layout bug: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from/pull/106 , waiting for it to upstream ;-)

Comment: This gives me a “404 File not found” error on my GitHub pages URL (the one eding in `.github.io`)

Comment: In addition to @MaximillianLaumeister, this means it's a http-level 200 and not a 301. Meaning you'd lose your SEO value for your pages.

Comment: Just to mention.. if you are using `gitlab` instead of `github`, you have use `plugins` instead of `gems`.

Answer (score 19):

## No.

Other answers talk about redirections with meta refresh or javascript. But the OP asked about **301** redirects. And here's the answer: *No*. It is not possible. Your site on GitHub Pages is static, so you don't have any control over the server.

Comment: This is the only fully correct general answer, as all other answers assume HTML content which will be parsed by a browser.  If you have, for example, a .tgz file which you want to serve from elsewhere but provide as a local URL, none of the above solutions will work because the file is served as application/octet-stream.

Answer (score 16):

To avoid the duplicate content, in a first time you can add a meta canonical like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://casperjs.org">
```

Comment: Ah yes I did forget this one, thank you for the hint :) But that doesn't solve the main issue which is the lack of permanent redirect, unfortunately :/

Answer (score 8):

You can redirect using Javascript after host detection, like this:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('http://niko.github.com') === 0) {
    window.location.href = 'http://casperjs.org{{ page.url }}';
}
```

But I agree, it's not an HTTP redirection.

Comment: Problem is that it won't solve the "google duplicate contents" issue I'm encountering right now… :/

Comment: In the meantime, you can add a rel="canonical" to your page, so Google won't declare those pages as "duplicate" : http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394

Comment: Actually, that's the official answer provided by the github support team: "Redirects like that aren't currently possible on Pages.  We might add it in the future.  You could use a little javascript magic to do a redirect for you, that's what we do on help.github.com."

Comment: Note: this kind of "solution" is not without issues. Read http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback

Answer (score 7):

Why didn't you use http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html?

That would give

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://casperjs.org/'" />
```

Comment: HTML redirect is a good way, thanks for your answer but it is not a permanent way. I upvote you anyway.

Answer (score 7):

**Manual layout method**

If you don't feel like using https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from it's easy to implement it yourself:

`a.md`:

```
---
layout: 'redirect'
permalink: /a
redir_to: 'http://example.com'
sitemap: false
---
```

`_layouts/redirect.html` based on [Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Redirecting...</title>
  {% comment %}
    Don't use 'redirect_to' to avoid conflict
    with the page redirection plugin: if that is defined
    it takes over.
  {% endcomment %}
  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ page.redir_to }}"/>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url={{ page.redir_to }}" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Redirecting...</h1>
  <a href="{{ page.redir_to }}">Click here if you are not redirected.<a>
  <script>location='{{ page.redir_to }}'</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now:

```
firefox localhost:4000/a
```

will redirect you to `example.com`.

Like this example, the `redirect-from` plugin does not generate 301s, only `meta` + JavaScript redirects.

We can verify what is going on with:

```
curl localhost:4000/a
```

Tested on GitHub pages v64, live demo at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io/tree/d783cc70a2e5c4d4dfdb1a36d518d5125071e236/r

Comment: @Downvoters: please explain so I can learn and improve info. I never retaliate.

Comment: this is the most useful and straightforward example on the internet. thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Github pages don't support anything like `.htaccess` or `nginx/conf`

https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/

so easiest way is:

HTML redirect:

`index.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.mywebsite.com/" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <p><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/">Redirect</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when switching the domain for my github pages site. I set up [rerouter](https://github.com/joeyAghion/rerouter) on Heroku to handle the 301 redirects to the new domain. It handles domain-to-domain redirects very simply, but you may have to modify it to handle your site's legacy domain+path location.

I described the steps in detail here:

http://joey.aghion.com/simple-301-redirects/

Answer (score 0):

Soft redirects only work if the content type is html (or similar). For binary files, let's say 'foo.pdf', github will not make a redirect possible as it sets the mime type according to the pdf extension and a soft redirect will just be interpreted as broken pdf.

That said, it is still possible to redirect correctly on github, but only use the following solution if:

- the server doesn't allow you to set a 301 redirect yourself (as is the case for github pages)
- the mime type is set by the file extension and it is a binary file (example: pdf, png, ...)
- none of the other solutions here work for you
- the resource is directly accessed by the user using a *browser* and it is not referenced by eg html (for example `<img src="...">`
- the old page is not indexed by google etal. anymore (ie., the sitemap points to the new url) as the solution will break google's crawling for the resource (google will only see a 404)
- you are allowed to provide custom 404 pages (as is the case for github pages)

the trick is to use embedded javascript in the 404 page that checks the url and redirects accordingly.

github pages allows you to define a 404 page by creating a file "404.html" in the root of the project (assuming the whole project is deployed via branch; otherwise put the file in the root of the deployed artifact)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'none'; script-src 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; img-src data:; connect-src 'self'"
    />
    <title>Page not found</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      // style your 404 nicely
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="redirect()">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>404</h1>
      <p><strong>File not found</strong></p>
      <p>The requested resource does not exist.</p>
      <div id="suggestions">
        <a href="/">Bring me back!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    function redirect() {
      if (window.location.pathname === '/old_incorrect_path/foo.pdf') {
        window.location = 'https://yourpage.com/path_to_correct_resource/foo.pdf';
      }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

The embedded javascript checks the requested pathname after the 404 page has loaded and will only redirect if it matches the old address. You can redirect multiple resources this way by chaining the ifs or just replace the host of the location for all urls if it's a full redirect for the whole page (but again use other methods where possible). Alternatively, you can also put the script at the top and let it execute right away instead of waiting for a full load, however, it might be nice for the user to see that their link was indeed a 404 before sending them to the correct place (and it's a good reminder for you to remove the hack once people overwhelmingly go to the correct link directly).

Note, setting a "Content-Security-Policy" to mostly 'unsafe-inline' makes sense as you shouldn't load other resources on a 404 page.

Please don't use this solution unless there is absolutely no other way to achieve the desired result. Again, it only works if the user directly browsers to the resource. Also, a web crawler will identify the pages as 404 and thus not count them as valid redirect. For example, google won't allow it for migrating a domain from the google search console (you need 301 redirects or valid soft redirects via `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://..." />` for google to accept the move). Also, referencing the resource via eg img will also break (as the image is seen as 404 only).

However, this is a valid solution for cases where, for one reason or another, users directly land on the resource while browsing and the referrers haven't updated the links yet (eg. stale google search result links or other pages linking to the old address). Their automated tooling (if they use any) will notify them that the link is returning a 404 and bring them to update the links (hopefully) eventually.