# How to make google index my custom domain instead of the github pages domain?

Tags: html, github, dns, github-pages

I have a splash page hosted in github pages for a client while we finish their official site.

Until a few days everything was ok but I now realized that [google is indexing](https://www.google.com/search?q=neue%20house&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS503US503&aq=f&oq=neue%20house&aqs=chrome.0.57j61l2j60j0l2.1899&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS503US503&sclient=psy-ab&q=neuehouse&oq=neuehouse&gs_l=serp.3..0i10j0j0i7j0.4471.4471.0.4778.1.1.0.0.0.0.75.75.1.1.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.g2PgjyZid_o&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.dmQ&fp=83aafd1de9483772&biw=1280&bih=755) the [github url](http://base-design.github.com/neuehouse/) instead of the [custom domain](http://neuehouse.com/).

I followed github instructions, i used the CNAME file in my repo, I setup the A domain for the top-level domain and the CNAME for the www. 
I looked all over the internet without luck. I tried using google webmaster tools, and I can't really use robots.txt because that would affect both.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I found the solution. Leaving it since it might be helpful to others.

I need to wait now for google to re-index, but it should do it.
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276817/301-redirect-for-site-hosted-at-github) and [this google article](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) a canonical link tag in the head should fix it.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.[website-url]"/>
```

I also added a js redirect trick to redirect the people coming from google.

```
if ( window.self === window.top ) { 
    // console.log("not in a frame") 
       window.location.href = 'http://www.[website-url]';
    }
```